# Cloud database for Azure multi-tenant application?

Tags: asp.net, azure, architecture, multi-tenant

I am starting to port one old desktop single tenant application into the cloud and wish to hear what would be your recommendation about the databases for my cloud-based multi-tenant application?

My basic requirement is simple:

1. For each tenant, its data is separate to any other tenants' data. I can easily backup, restore, export the data for one single tenant without affecting other tenants.
2. I don't really want to care about multi-tenancy in the business logic code. It should look like a single tenant application behind the security layer, no tenant ID pass around etc.
3. Easy to query using some mature technology like LINQ.
4. Availability and scalability, of course, easy to set up replicas, fail-over and scaling up and down etc.

I have gone through some investigations about multi-tenant application development. I have noticed SQL databases from Azure and AWS are both very expensive(the cost for just SQL database instance is close to the license fee of the original application), so I definitely can't use separate SQL database instances for tenants.

Now I'm reading this book [Developing Multi-tenant Applications for the Cloud, 3rd Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx), and it uses Azure Storage Service to implement multi-tenancy. I haven't finished the book yet, it seems you still have to handle the multi-tenancy by yourself and the sample code is already out of date.

I have seen lots of SO questions compare Azure Table Storage with MongoDB. The MongoDB is very new to me, not sure whether it could be easily used to fulfill my requirements?

And I have seen RavenDB as well, it does support multi-tenancy out of box. But I didn't see some good sample code about how to use it in Azure app development.

Hope to hear some good advices from awesome SO guys.

Answer (score 1):

I would better opt with RavenDB on top of MongoDB. Even Raven is a new comer in to the game, it supports most of the features which traditional SQL supports.

Also to make up a decisions the volume of data you are dealing is a also a key decision pointer. Also the amount of traffic you are expecting.

Also keep in mind that operational costs and development efforts. HA and DR scenarios can be problematic when you use Raven or Mongo because of the fact that you need to host them. But when it comes to Azure Storage, it by defaults protects you to a maximum extent by maintaining 3 copies of information.

So I would suggest you to carefully make the trade offs and opt wisely based on your business needs, cost optimization, development and operational effort.

Comment: The volume of data is not big in fact. The project is a cloud based real estate management app. The users just need to use it to record lease activities and generate statements etc. I would think it is just few transactions per day for each user. Because the size of the app is small, I am hoping not to spend too much effort on implement the multi tenancy myself, but use some existing tools, libs, and maybe DBs. Thanks for recommending Raven. Do you know about some good tutorial of how to use it in Azure or cloud? Any advice would be greatly helpful because I am seeking needles in the sea now.

Comment: What do you mean HA and DR?

Comment: HADR mean High availability and disaster recovery situations. Say if you host your DB on a Azure VM. What if that VM goes down due to power failure or network connectivity. What if the complete Data Centre goes down? how fast you can resume your services? So things like this needs to be considered when you go for Cloud. Even though Azure gives you 99.9 SLA on all their services, still we should be able to accommodate transient fault, because of the fact that everything is based on REST API calls. I would suggest Azure table storage for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single instance of your application for each tenant is a very expensive way to implement an application, however I realise that if an application was developed with a single tenant in mind, then the costs of changing over can be high.

First can we start out with why you have a desktop application connecting to a database at another location. The latency can really slow down an application. Ideally you would want a locally installed database and have it sync with the cloud DB, or add in appropriate caching into your application.

However the DB would still need to differentiate the clients.

Why do you need this to go to a cloud database? Is it for backup purposes, not installing a DB locally on a clients machine, accessing the same data from many machines or something else?

Unless your application is extremely large, I would recommend rewriting it for multi-tenant to one SQL Azure database. The architecture chosen at the beginning of the project doesn't suit your requirements now. As you expand you will run into further issues.

Comment: Thanks Adam, the original desktop app is using local db not a remote one. My plan is to write a cloud web app so that the users of the app could access it from anywhere. And the cloud based db is of course for the new cloud app. What do you mean rewriting for multitenent to one SQL Azure db? Is that using tenantID for each table to differentiate data? I am just concerned about how I can handle backup and restore data for a single user but not affecting others.

Comment: Yes that would mean having a tenantID on every applicable table. You would then do backups of the whole DB each time, not for a particular user. If you wanted people to do their own individual backups and restores then you would need to write additional code to export user data and import/overwrite it again.

I am not sure what your app entails as with apps I maintain, not one user has every asked for a full restore to a previous state. However instead of doing hard deletes in the database, I use a deleted flag on each row. So that way their specific data can be retrieved if needed.